# Flask variable not transferring to the next page

Tags: python, flask

I'm having a problem with Flask.
I declare a variable before any routing is done and before any function is declared. The variable is set to empty string initially.

Then, when user clicks on submit button, the value of that variable get's changed, and since it's declared before anything else it should be accessable from another function (the function which renders another page).

I can access the variable, but it's empty for some reason.

Here's my code:

```
predicted_output = ""

.....

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
......
    pred_s = str(prediction)
    m = Money(amount=pred_s, currency='EUR')

    predicted_output = str(m)
    return redirect(url_for("result"))


@app.route("/result")
def result():
    return render_template("result.html", the_final_value=predicted_output)
```

AND HTML:

```
<div class="text-out-main">
    {{ the_final_value }}
</div>
```

Where did I make mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [session](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#sessions) to store values between requests:

> In addition to the request object there is also a second object called session which allows you to store information specific to a user from one request to the next. This is implemented on top of cookies for you and signs the cookies cryptographically. What this means is that the user could look at the contents of your cookie but not modify it, unless they know the secret key used for signing.

For example:

```
from flask import session

app.secret_key = 'dev'

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    pred_s = str(prediction)
    m = Money(amount=pred_s, currency='EUR')

    session['predicted_output'] = str(m)  # store it to session
    return redirect(url_for("result"))


@app.route("/result")
def result():
    predicted_output = session['predicted_output']  # get it from session
    return render_template("result.html", the_final_value=predicted_output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send data during the redirection and catch it after, like this :

```
return redirect(url_for("result", the_final_value=predicted_output))

@app.route("/result")
def result(the_final_value):
    return render_template("result.html", the_final_value=the_final_value)
```